# Probit Regression in R

Tags: r

My question might seem very basic but since am new to R, I am struggling with it. Shall be grateful if I could get some insight...
I need to conduct a probit regression with respect to temperature and people's preference (desire warmer or desire cooler). The preference is therefore my dependent binary variable. I basically desire a plot in which on the y axis there is percentage of respondents desiring warmer/cooler and the x axis has temperature. The plot must therefore have two probit curves- one representing desire warmer and the other curve indicating desire cooler. I am interested at the intersection of the two curves.
Shall be grateful if someone could help me in the R code for the same.

Comment: To facilitate answer to your question, it would be very useful to provide a sample of your data using dput(mydata), and also to explain what you already tried.

Comment: Do you have atleast what functions in R you will use or how to get the data you want into R? Without atleast bare minimum code, I don't know where you are in the process. Thank you